# Kivy: scheduling sounds with kivy.clock for a timer

Tags: python, audio, kivy, clock, kivy-language

I have created a timer that counts down from a random number to zero, then once it has hit zero it moves to a new screen and counts down from a random number again. I would like for there to be a sound as the timer reaches 3, 2, 1 and then a different sound of 0, but I am unsure of how to implement this.

I have tried loading the sound file as an mp3 through SoundLoader and the function is called when the button is pressed to begin the timer. My current understanding is that the function will check if self.a =3,2,1 or 0 only once as the function is called, so the kivy.clock Clock.schedule_interval() function is required to check the value of self.a every second. I have tried this (shown in the code below), but the timer runs for one second and then crashes, displaying the error message TypeError: sound() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

### **py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from random import randint
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass

class FourthWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    a = NumericProperty(0)
    b = NumericProperty(0)
    run_t = NumericProperty(30)
    min = NumericProperty(5)
    max = NumericProperty(5)
    sound_done = SoundLoader.load('beep-01a.mp3')
    sound_finishing = SoundLoader.load('beep-07.mp3')

    def sound(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.sound, 1)
        if self.a == 0:
            self.sound_done.play()
        if self.a == 1:
            self.sound_finishing.play()
        if self.a == 2:
            self.sound_finishing.play()
        if self.a == 3:
            self.sound_finishing.play()


    def proceed(self):
            self.reset()
            self.start()
            self.count_up()
            self.sound()
            self.ids.main_window.manager.current = 'low'

    def reset(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    def start(self, *args):
        self.a = randint(self.min, self.max)
        self.anim = Animation(a = 0, duration = self.a)
            if rand == 0:
                self.ids.main_window.manager.current = 'low'
            elif rand == 1:
                self.ids.main_window.manager.current = 'medium'
            elif rand == 2:
                self.ids.main_window.manager.current = 'high'
            self.anim.bind(on_complete = self.start)
        self.anim.start(self)

    def count_up(self):
        self.anim = Animation(b = self.run_t, duration = self.run_t)
        self.anim.bind(on_complete = self.finish_callback)
        self.anim.start(self)

    def finish_callback(self, animation, param):
        Animation.cancel_all(self)


kv = Builder.load_file("final.kv")

class PageScrollerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PageScrollerApp().run()
```

### **kv file**

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
        id: main_window
    SecondWindow:
        id: second_window
    ThirdWindow:
        id: third_window
    FourthWindow:
        id: fourth_window

<MainWindow>:
    name: "home"

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            text: "Go!"
            on_release:
                root.manager.proceed()


<SecondWindow>:
    name: 'low'

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: count_down1
            text: str(round(root.manager.a, 1))
            size_hint: 0.28, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.55}
        Label:
            id: count_up1
            text: str(round(root.manager.b, 1))
            size_hint: 0.28, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.3}


<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "medium"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: count_down2
            text: str(round(root.manager.a, 1))
            size_hint: 0.28, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.55}
        Label:
            id: count_up2
            text: str(round(root.manager.b, 1))
            size_hint: 0.28, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.3}

<FourthWindow>:
    name: "high"

    FloatLayout:
       Label:
            id: count_down3
            text: str(round(root.manager.a, 1))
            size_hint: 0.28, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.55}
        Label:
            id: count_up3
            text: str(round(root.manager.b, 1))
            size_hint: 0.28, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.3}
```

### **EDIT**

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\User\.kivy\logs\kivy_19- 
07-12_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC 
v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at 
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, 
img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <beep-01a.ogg>
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <beep-07.ogg>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.13467 Compatibility Profile 
Context 21.19.414.1792'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ATI Technologies Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'AMD Radeon R7 Graphics'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not 
docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

I have tried to strip the code of anything irrelevant to the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use [Kivy Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) object to call a callback function, you must provide `dt` (`dt` means delta-time). If you don't, you will encounter,

> TypeError: sound() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

## Solution

Use `lambda` function to skip this. Replace `Clock.schedule_interval(self.sound, 1)` with `Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.sound(), 1)`

### Snippets

```
def sound(self):
    int_round_a = int(round(self.a))
    print(f"self.a={self.a}, int_round_a={int_round_a}")
    if int_round_a == 0:
        self.sound_done.play()
    elif int_round_a == 1:
        self.sound_finishing.play()
    elif int_round_a == 2:
        self.sound_finishing.play()
    elif int_round_a == 3:
        self.sound_finishing.play()

def proceed(self):
    self.reset()
    self.start()
    self.count_up()
    Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.sound(), 1)
    self.ids.main_window.manager.current = 'low'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is brilliant! And thank you also for pointing out the need for the int_round_a value. The program does now run properly, and it appears that the sound() function is being called as it should be, but there is no sound coming out. I looked at the log and there are 2 warnings [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <beep-01a.mp3>
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <beep-07.mp3>. Do you know if this is part of the same issue?

Comment: Please update your post with the complete Kivy Logger. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I have now edited the original question so that it is included under the title "edit".

Comment: With reference to the warnings, `[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <beep-01a.ogg>` and `[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <beep-07.ogg>` , it is not able to load/play `ogg` file. Try changing those files to `mp3`.

Comment: Hi Ikolim, thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately when I change to mp3 files the same problem persists and I get the same warning messages. I have also noticed that since having tried to implement these sounds my "home" button causes the program to crash, with an error message reading: line 40, in sound self.sound_done.play()  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'. I'm thinking I might write a new question to stack overflow, because this seems bigger than my original question, but any advise you may have would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you able to play `wav` files in `kivy-examples/audio/*.wav`?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm very new to this. How do I do that?

Comment: You have to install Kivy examples using `python -m pip install kivy_examples==1.11.1`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have now installed it, but where/how do I access it? Sorry I'm having to ask you so many questions, but my google searches are returning nothing useful. I do appreciate the help!

Comment: In Windows 10, the Kivy examples can be found at:

`C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\share\kivy-examples`
Replace "usr" with your user name